# Set coroutine to be started on click for every Button in a list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `List<GameObject> button_list` in Unity and want to add my `ChangeScene` coroutine to the `onClick` of each item's `Button` (each game object has a `Button` component)

How can I do this?

```
public List<GameObject> button_list = new List<GameObject>();

private IEnumerator ChangeScene()
{
    yield return SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(toLoad);
    yield return SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(toUnload);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried Unity but since the list is of GameObject when not add the method in that? Each item in the list will be having that method then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an anonymous function starting the `ChangeScene` coroutine as a listener to each button's `onClick`:

```
foreach (GameObject go in button_list) 
{ 
    go.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => StartCoroutine(ChangeScene()));
}
```